# How find this value $\frac{a^3}{(a-p)(a-q)}+\frac{b^3}{(b-p)(b-q)}+\frac{c^3}{(c-p)(c-q)}$

Tags: calculus

let $p,q$ is a 
$$(x-a)(x-b)+(x-b)(x-c)+(x-c)(x-a)=0$$ roots,find this value
$$\dfrac{a^3}{(a-p)(a-q)}+\dfrac{b^3}{(b-p)(b-q)}+\dfrac{c^3}{(c-p)(c-q)}$$
where $a,b,c$ is give numbers.

I know this  Lagrange interpolation
$$\dfrac{a^3}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\dfrac{b^3}{(b-a)(b-c)}+\dfrac{c^3}{(c-a)(c-b)}=a+b+c$$

But my problem is different.so how find it?

Comment: $p,q$ roots of $$(x-a)(x-b)+(x-b)(x-c)+(x-c)(x-a) = 0$$
implies
$$3 (x-p)(x-q) = (x-a)(x-b)+(x-b)(x-c)+(x-c)(x-a)\\
\implies 3(a-p)(a-q) = (a-b)(a-c)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity of derivation, I will assume $a,b,c$ are distinct.

Let $f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$, we have

$$f'(x) = (x-a)(x-b)+(x-b)(x-c)+(x-c)(x-a)$$

Since $p,q$ are roots of the equation $f'(x) = 0$, by comparing the coefficient of the $x^2$ term, we have

$$(x-p)(x-q) = \frac13 f'(x)$$

So the expression $\mathcal{E}$ we want to evaluate is equal to

$$\mathcal{E} = 3 \left( \frac{a^3}{f'(a)} + \frac{b^3}{f'(b)} + \frac{c^3}{f'(c)} \right)$$

Now consider the partial fraction decomposition of $\displaystyle\;\frac{x^3}{f(x)} - 1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{x^3}{f(x)} - 1
=  \frac{x^3-f(x)}{f(x)}
&= \frac{a^3 - f(a)}{f'(a)(x-a)} + \frac{b^3 - f(b)}{f'(b)(x-b)} + \frac{c^3 - f(c)}{f'(c)(x-c)}\\
&= \frac{a^3}{f'(a)(x-a)} + \frac{b^3}{f'(b)(x-b)} + \frac{c^3}{f'(c)(x-c)}
\end{align}$$
Multiply both sides by $3x$ and sending $x$ to infinity, we find

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{E} 
= \lim_{x\to\infty} 3x \times \text{RHS}
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} 3x \times \text{LHS}\\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} 3x \left(\frac{x^3 - f(x)}{f(x)}\right)\\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} 3 x \left[ \frac{(a+b+c)x^2 - (ab+bc+ca)x + abc}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}\right]\\
&= 3(a+b+c)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

your first equation could be written as
$$3x^2-2(a+b+c)x+ab+bc+ac=0$$
because $p,q$ are roots of this equation, so we have
$$p+q=\frac{2(a+b+c)}{3},\quad pq=\frac{ab+bc+ac}{3}$$
then the second equation is
$$\dfrac{a^3}{(a-p)(a-q)}+\dfrac{b^3}{(b-p)(b-q)}+\dfrac{c^3}{(c-p)(c-q)}\\
=\dfrac{a^3}{a^2-(p+q)a+pq}+\dfrac{b^3}{b^2-(p+q)b+pq}+\dfrac{c^3}{c^2-(p+q)c+pq}$$
using $p+q,pq$ in this equation, you have the result.